# When opportunity is greater than 5000

Tags: trigger

I am trying to do,If opportunity amount is greater than 5000 then send email to the account manager, using any default template?

Comment: Workflow rule with a email alert

Comment: User28787, how are you trying to do this and what do you want to ask us ?

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use big deal alert for this, though you also need to include probability which makes sense in most use cases.

Comment: Just an FYI that it seems only 1 BDA can be active at any time. There is a Salesforce Idea here to have that limit increased: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpTEAA0

Answer (score 1):

For email alert you should opt workflow Rule, for which you can follow the steps below :-

Step1:-Create the  new Rule in wrokflow section,Select opportunity as sObject;
Step2:-Enter the Rule Name as you want,select Evalution Criteria as a created and select Rule Criteria as ammount is greater-than-5000;
[image]
Step 3:- choose action as New Email Alert
[image]
Step4:-Enter the descripation as you want, add email template, then select Recipient Type as role ,then select account Manager from Available Recipient.
[image]
step5:-click on Done

[image]

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: I am trying to do with trigger code.

Comment: Is is posible to do with trigger.. i am trying

Comment: Hi Ajay.... please help me to do this same above process with trigger code....